# Implementing .equals(Die aDie) method and static variables

Tags: java

I am creating the method .equals(Die aDie) in my program. Do I compare every instance variable including static ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static variables, by definition, are not instance variables, and will therefore always be equal across all instances of the same class.

Answer (score 4):

> boolean equals(Die aDie)

is wrong, classes will call the `equals(Object)` method and ignore your equals(Die). Also implement the `int hashCode()` method using the same fields that equals(Object) uses.

```
 @Override public boolean equals(Object aDie){
     if(aDie == null || aDie.getClass() != Die.class)return false;
     if(aDie == this)return true;
     Die other = (Die)aDie;
     ...   
 }
 @Override public int hashCode(){
     ...
 }
```

You can ignore static fields since they are the same for every Die.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not the static ones.

Whether you compare *all* the instance variables depends on what determines the "identity" of your objects, i.e. when do you consider them equal? This can only be decided in the context of your particular application - we'd need more information.

For example, if you had a class representing books, you might only compare the ISBN number to determine whether two books are the same book, if you just wanted to store metadata about them (title, author). If you merged two such databases, you'd want to eliminate duplicate records.

BUT, if you were implementing a library catalogue of actual physical books, each individual copy is important and different, so you might compare ISBN *and* copy number. If you merged two libraries, you'd expect to be able to detect duplicate copies.

Answer (score 0):

You would compare every instance variable.

Static variables are guaranteed to be equal, as they are class-specific, not instance-specific, so you don't have to worry about comparing them.

Comment: Only instance variables. If `Die.sides` is static, comparing `Die a.sides` to `Die b.sides` **can never** be false. Statics are identical in value and in memory location.

Answer (score 0):

It would make no sense, both because with equals() you compare instances *and* because, well, they are static: what would you compare them to, themselves?

Answer (score 0):

It is useless to compare static data, as it is shared among all instances of your `Die` class. But you can compare the various fields by accessing them directly (see example below). Note that if your `Die` object has complex fields (such as instances of `Map`, `Set`, etc), you should also call the `equals` methods on those objects (again, see example below).

If you want to provide an `equals ()` method, you should override the one provided in the `Object` class (`equals (Object anOtherObject`), rather than overloading it, or at least make sure you also override `equals (Object anOtherObject)` to make sure that it returns the correct value too (the default implementation only checks if it's the same instance). And in your method you should then check if `anOtherObject` is an instance of `Die`.

Here's an example, assuming that your `Die` class has 3 fields: `String name`, `int value` and `Map<Integer> complexField`:

```
public boolean equals (Object anOtherObject) {
    if (anOtherObject == this) {
        return true;
    }

    if (!anOtherObject instanceof Die) {
        return false;
    }

    Die otherDie = (Die) anOtherObject;

    if (this.value != otherDie.value ||
            !this.name.equals (otherDie.name) ||
            !this.complexField.equals (otherDie.complexField)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Josh Bloch's "*Effective Java*" has a very details section on how to correctly implement `equals`. You should definitely read it.

Answer (score 0):

When a variable is declared with the keyword “static”, its called a “class variable”. All instances share the same copy of the variable (always be equal across all instances of the same class). A class variable can be accessed directly with the class, without the need to create a instance.